# Synergy Pro copy/paste and scroll on Windows 10 fails

Tags: windows, synergy

Synergy Pro 1.8.4
3 Windows 10 machines (had the same issue on Windows 7)

The copy/paste and client scrolling features OFTEN (10 times a day) stops working.
I can get the functionality back by opening Synergy on the server (there is no sys tray icon so I have to open the app) and clicking on the Apply button.

Server settings
Port: 24800
Interface:
Elevate: Always
Use SSL encyiption: not checked

I tried check off the SSL encryption function but mouse performance is unusable on the client machines

Answer (score 5):

The last few versions of Synergy have improved copy/paste and scrolling functionality from 1.8.4 to the current release of 1.8.7.

Updating should fix the issues you've had. You can find the latest version on the [Synergy download](http://symless.com/download/) page.

Answer (score 1):

Try to "Run Wizard" again and skip activation. Also, disable SSL. That should help. If all fails, try to find version 1.7.6 and roll with that as it's the most stable copy/paste edition in my experience.

Hope this helps.